ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run"
virtualbox- maquina virtual
Ubuntu 22.04 using
avr-gdb (GDB version 12.1)
avr-gcc (gcc version 11.4)
estoy intentando depurar un programa. se compila bien y me devuelve el archivo .elf correcto.
tiene estas caracteristicas:
elena@Elena:~/Documents/1288/pclqube$ file pcl_digtest.elf

pcl_digtest.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Atmel AVR 8-bit, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped

elena@Elena:/usr/bin$ uname -a
Linux Elena 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Usando VScode y avr-gdb e intento abrir el archivo pcl_digtest.elf y me encuentro con el siguiente error:
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". Don't know how to run. Try "help target". The program '/home/elena/Documents/1288/pclqube/pcl_digtest.elf' has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a).

usando GDB solo, tengo el mismo error

alguna idea? he intentado hacer esto y no funciona:
echo -en '\x90\x90' | sudo dd of=/usr/bin/gdb count=2 bs=1 conv=notrunc seek=$((0x335C7D))

